# android notification problem in ( tecno,Xiaomi,infinix , ...) phone

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, alarmmanager

how can i make may android application is allowed to send notification when it is close from **phone security or from phone master app**

i need to get permission from user to add may application to white list

as this figure

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx9RA.jpg)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/44agV.jpg)

i will search and try different solutions but not solved may problem

Comment: I highly doubt you can programatically.  It would kind of defeat the purpose of blocking them

Comment: @GabeSechan
"Is it possible to make an application run in the background permanently?"

Comment: No.  It never has been on Android.  And in modern ANdroid you're extremely limited.  But explain why you want to do that, there's probably a way to achieve it without being running constantly

Comment: @GabeSechan    i make simple (to do list app) with notification i used alarm manager it is work correctly but when the app is close alarm manager don't post any notification

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.